# facebook open graph dynamic by php not working

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I need dynamically create Open Graph tags.

My code is:

```
<meta property='og:title'  content='<? echo $_SERVER['city']; ?> '>
```

If i load page on webbrowser title is good, but Facebook does not seem to recognize them.

How do I dynamically set Open Graph tags properly?

Comment: Maybe you mean `$_POST['city']` or `$_GET['city']` ?

Comment: $_POST['city'] not working  $_GET['city'] working,facebook didn't see this

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['city'] isn't a [PHP Server variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

og:title should be the [title of your object](http://ogp.me/) as it should appear within the graph.

Once you've put the correct content into the meta tag, Facebook should pick it up correctly.

Comment: ?? can do this or not ?

Comment: You say $_GET['city'] is working. If I am to assume your URL has ?city=cityname in it then I would expect your meta tag to render as <meta property='og:title'  content='cityname'> Can you post the rest of the HTML which contains your Open Graph headers?

Comment: working only if i run site on webbrowser open graph don't read it